# registered app does not appears in AAD B2C Identity Experience Framework to run the custom policy

Tags: azure

i have registered my application IN AAD B2C following the Microsoft documentation "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy".
but i couldn't able to see my registered app in the "select application" dropdown menu, while trying to run the B2C_1A_signup_signin policy.
i selected the option of "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory – Multitenant)"
that is the step 6 of the "Registration an Application" step to register the Application.
looking forward of any help, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

got the issue fixed MS documentation is outdated and misleading,
they said to select wrong for account types.

instead of selecting:**"Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory – Multitenant)"**
use this:"**Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)**".